# Module loading data from database on require

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make a module that loads categories from database once so I can query it with categoryName and it will return the model. like this categoryResolver('sweaters'). I'm using objection.js

Currently I have the following code

```
'use strict'

const CategoryModel = require('./models/Category.js')
var categories

async function getCategories () {
  categories = await CategoryModel.query()
}

getCategories()

module.exports = function (categoryName) {    
  return (categories.filter(c => {
    return c.name === category
  }))
}
```

How can I make sure categories has been initialized before querying? 
Checking if categories has been set and waiting until it has seems like a bad solution.

Comment: Filter will give you an empty array of the categories variable has not been initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: added demo snippet

You could make your query function await the `getCategories` call before running the filter.

```
// categories is a Promise
const categories = getCategories();

module.exports = async function (categoryName) {    
  return categories.then(cats => cats.filter(c => c.name === categoryName));
}
```

The promise will resolve once and then be basically instantaneously resolved.

External users would then treat the return value as a promise, by awaiting:

```
const sweaters = await categoryResolver('sweaters');
// do something with sweaters
```

or thenning:

```
categoryResolver('sweaters')
  .then(sweaters => {
    // do something with sweaters
  });
```

In the following demo you'll notice that the initial resolve takes 2 seconds but the subsequent calls resolve immediately.

```js
// mock data
const data = [{
    name: 'sweaters',
    items: ['sweater 1', 'sweater 2', 'sweater 3']
  },
  {
    name: 'wookies',
    items: ['wookie 1', 'wookie 2', 'wookie 3']
  },
  {
    name: 'hats',
    items: ['hat 1', 'hat 2', 'hat 3']
  },
];

// simulated category fetch; waits 2 seconds and resolves with mock data
const categories = new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve(data), 2000);
});

async function categoryResolver(category) {
  return categories.then(cats => cats.filter(c => c.name === category));
}

// usage with await
async function goAwait(category) {
  const cat = await categoryResolver(category);
  console.log(`awaited ${category}`, cat);
}

// usage with then
function goThen(category) {
  categoryResolver(category).then(cat => {
    console.log(`thenned ${category}`, cat);
  });
}

goAwait('sweaters');
goThen('sweaters');
goAwait('wookies');
goThen('hats');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I get TypeError: (intermediate value).then is not a function at (await categories).then. 

I also removed "}))"

Comment: Oops. I updated my answer to fix that problem. I was awaiting *and* thenning. Fixed.

Comment: I added a runnable demo snippet that shows both usages.